# How do I write an expression that deference a pointer in GDB?

Tags: c++, assembly, x86, gdb, gnu

Suppose EAX contains a pointer to some value (doubleword).

What I'd like to do is to examine this value, i.e. writing an expression like `x /1wx [eax]`.

However, GDB complains when writing `[eax]` in expressions, saying that syntax is wrong.

How would I deference a pointer in GDB?

Comment: Remember that gdb syntax is C-like, even when you're debugging asm.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the other answer noted, you can the $eax to look at that specific register.

```
(gdb) x /1wx $eax
0x400523d <main>:  0xe5894855
```

'info reg' will give a register dump that contains lots of useful information.

You can also cast in gdb to dereference a pointer.

```
(gdb) print /x *(int*)0x400523d
$3 = 0xe5894855
```

I use this method often while debugging.  It is useful when digging inside a complex class/structure for pointers.  Following a chain of pointers is often simplified but just grabbing the address and looking at the dereference.

Comment: Thank you, so in essence to deference a pointer I should just use C-syntax like yours "*(int*)0x40052d", where 0x40052d is the pointers value?

Comment: Yes that is correct. gdb handles all the base type, int, float, double, etc.  Simple user types are supported as well.  C++ template types can be tricky to type but are supported

Comment: Don't u miss a "3" in your cast "/x *(int*)0x40052d" ?

Comment: Thanks for your help and knowledge.

Answer (score 4):

You can refer to registers by common names using `$` before. For example

```
print $rax
```

to print `rax` value, or

```
print *$rax
```

to dereference value in `rax` as pointer.

https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Registers.html

Comment: Thank for your helpful answer.